# realloc() for NUMA Systems using HWLOC

Tags: c++, linux, memory, numa

I have a several custom allocators that provide different means to allocate memory based on different policies. One of them allocates memory on a defined NUMA node. The interface to the allocator is straight-forward

```
template<typename config>
class NumaNodeStrategy
{

public:

    static void *allocate(const size_t sz){}

    static void *reallocate(void *old, size_t sz, size_t old_sz){}

    static void deallocate(void *p, size_t sz){}
};
```

The allocation itself is handled using the `hwloc_alloc_membind_nodeset()` methods with the according parameters set for allocation policies etc. Howver, hwloc only provides methods for allocation and free'ing memory and I was wondering how should I implement `reallocate()`.

Two possible solutions:

1. Allocate new memory area and `memcpy()` the data
2. Use `hwloc_set_membind_nodeset()` to set the memory allocation / binding policy for the nodeset and use plain `malloc()` / `posix_memalign()` and `realloc()`.

Can anyone help me in getting this right?

**Update:**

I try to make the question more specific: Is there a possibility to perform a `realloc()` using `hwloc` without allocating new memory and moving the pages around?

Comment: What about using libnuma directly? http://linux.die.net/man/3/numa

Comment: Because `libnuma` may produce wrong results (showing wrong cpu bindings for numa nodes etc) and I was hoping to use `hwloc` instead. https://gist.github.com/1125022

Comment: Hmm.. Is the memory binding setting node-specific? So, if the node 5 calls realloc on memory, owned by node 5, will libc's realloc do same-node memory allocation?

Answer (score 2):

To reply to the edit:
There's no realloc in hwloc, and we currently have no plan to add one. If you see preceisely what you want (C prototype of the function), feel free to add a ticket to https://svn.open-mpi.org/trac/hwloc

To reply to ogsx: The memory binding isn't specific, it's virtual memory area specific, and possibly thread-specific. If you realloc, the libc doesn't do anything special.
1) If it can realloc within the same page, you get memory on the same node. Good, but rare, especially for large buffers.
2) If it realloc in a different page (most of the cases for large buffers), it depends if the corresponding page have already been allocated in physical memory by the malloc lib in the past (malloc'ed and freed in virtual memory, but still allocated in physical memory)
2.a) If the virtual page has been allocated, it may have been allocated on another node for various reasons in the past, you're screwed.
2.b) If the new virtual page has not been allocated yet, the default is to allocate on the current node. If you specified a binding with set_area_membind() or mbind() earlier, it'll be allocated on the right node. You may be happy in this case.

In short, it depends on a lot of things. If you don't want to bother with the malloc lib doing complex/hidden internal things, and especially if your buffers are large, doing mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS) instead of malloc is a simple way to be sure that pages are allocated when you really want them. And you even have mremap to do something similar to realloc.

alloc becomes mmap(length) + set_area_membind
realloc becomes mremap + set_area_membind (on the entire mremap'ed buffer)

Never used that but looks interesting.

Answer (score 1):

The [hwloc_set_area_membind_nodeset](http://www.open-mpi.de/projects/hwloc/doc/v1.2/group__hwlocality__membinding.php#gade5e2c28ea8475a479bf2b1df36c6ccd) does the trick, doesn't it?

```
 HWLOC_DECLSPEC int     
  hwloc_set_area_membind_nodeset (hwloc_topology_t topology, 
    const void *addr, size_t len, hwloc_const_nodeset_t nodeset, 
    hwloc_membind_policy_t policy, int flags)
```

> Bind the already-allocated memory identified by (addr, len) to the NUMA node(s) in nodeset.
>
> Returns:

- -1 with errno set to ENOSYS if the action is not supported
- -1 with errno set to EXDEV if the binding cannot be enforced

On linux, this call is implemented via [`mbind`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/mbind.2.html)  It works only if pages in the area was not touched, so it is just more correct way to move memory region in your second solution. **UPDATE** there is a MPOL_MF_MOVE* flags to move touched data.

The only syscall to move pages without reallocate-and-copy I know is [move_pages](http://linux.die.net/man/2/move_pages)

> move_pages moves a set of pages in the address space of a executed process to a different NUMA node.

Comment: As you stated `hwloc_set_area_membind_nodeset` only allows to move allocated memory to a different node, while I was looking for something like `numa_realloc()` in `libnuma`.

Answer (score 1):

You're wrong. mbind can move pages that have been touched. You just need to add MPOL_MF_MOVE. That's what `hwloc_set_area_membind_nodeset()` does if you add the flag `HWLOC_MEMBIND_MIGRATE`.

`move_pages` is just a different way to do it (more flexible but a bit slower because you can move independant pages to different places). Both mbind with `MPOL_MF_MOVE` and move_pages (and migrate_pages) end up using the exact same `migrate_pages()` function in mm/migrate.c once they have converted the input into a list of pages.

Comment: So, grundprinzip can do a usual realloc and then call `hwloc_set_area_membind_nodeset()` with `HWLOC_MEMBIND_MIGRATE`?

Comment: Yes.
Or he may also do hwloc_alloc_membind_nodeset() to allocate the new buffer on the right memory node, then memcpy manually from the old buffer to the new one, and then free the old buffer. You have to copy at some point anyway so it's better to copy after binding the final buffer.

Comment: I know that it is possible to migrate pages, but as stated in the question I want to increase the allocated memory area on the same node and want to avoid copying.

Comment: There's no easy way to increase without copying, so increasing on the same node without copying would be even harder.